# How to stop ListView.builder from scrolling when new items are added to the list?

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a chat screen in which I have a reversed ListView.builder which shows the chats.
The problem is when new messages are added to the list, the ListView scrolls, which makes it hard to scroll up and read the previous messages. How can I make the ListView scroll as the new messages arrive only if the ListView's offset is 0 (the start of the ListView), and stop it from scrolling when the offset is not 0 (somewhere else in the ListView)?

Comment: If you show code it makes answering easier. After digging into the source code (with CNTL+left click), I found line 630 of scroll_view.dart: "The [ListView.builder] constructor takes an [IndexedWidgetBuilder], which builds the children on demand. This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible." ... Notice that last sentence, "only for those children that are actually visible". If you're calling ListView.builder, is that forcing it to make the new one visible? Maybe...

Comment: Have you found a solution?